# Angular 4. Как правильно передавать File в метод POST?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular2, express

**Нужно передать сам файл а не данные о файле**
**auth.service.ts** 
Принимаю объект с данными из компонента регистрации `register.component.ts`

```
registerUser(user) { 
  console.log(user);

  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  return this.http.post(this.domain + 'authentication/register', 
  JSON.stringify(user), options).map(res => res.json());
}
```

`console.log` отображает все необходимые данные, в том числе с сам файл

```
{
  address: "124124124"

  avatar: File {name: "big_5ae4786f899b2c8bf63b3ee481f0daf2503e402b.jpg", 
  lastModified: 1503854933277, lastModifiedDate: Sun Aug 27 2017 20:28:53 
  GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима)), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 436719, …}

  birthday: {day:"1",month:"January",year:"1967"}
  email: "example@gmail.com"
  password: "password"
  phone: "123123412"
  username: "Denis"
}
```

Отправляем данные...

```
authentication.js(express.js routing)
```

Принимаем данные...

```
router.post('/register', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
 console.log(req.body);
)};
```

Но теперь в теле запроса файл отсутствует.

```
{
  address: "124124124"

  avatar: {}

  birthday: {day:"1",month:"January",year:"1967"}
  email: "denisod93@gmail.com"
  password: "kamekadZ227@"
  phone: "123123412"
  username: "Denis"
}
```

Что ни так я делаю в функции `registerUser()` и какие параметры необходимы для метода POST ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос: Вы хотите данные о файле передать или сам файл?

`JSON.Stringify` конвертирует все в строку, в том числе и ваш Файл.

Если `console.log` выводит "объект" описания файла, то Stringify в большинстве браузеров выводят или пустую строку или в строку в духе `[Object {}]`.

Если хотите передать именно файл, то есть два варианта:

1. нужно отдельно передавать файл и JSON, как два отдельных параметра, через

   ```
   let formData: FormData = new FormData();
   formData.append('avatar', file, file.name);
   formData.append('user', user);
   return this.http.post(this.domain + 'authentication/register', formData, options)....
   ```
2. Или загонять файл через **base64**

Comment: Теперь я получаю просто пустой объект {}

Comment: Если Вы используете `Express.js` то для `FormData`, нужно дополнительно поставить и использовать пакет для его разбора, например `body-parser`.

Comment: Или `express-formidable`

Comment: Я использую body-parser **app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));** Может каких то параметров не хватает в urlencoded ?

Comment: При использовании Content-Type тело запроса получается пустым

Comment: И еще после преобразования объекта user в formData, formData имеет пустой объект

Comment: а что Вы formData хотите увидеть в FormData? Содержимое этого объекта скрыто нативной реализация браузера, и содержимое Вы там не увидите. Тоже самое с другой стороны. `console.log` требует строку на входе, так что он FormData пытается привести к ней, и получается в лучшем случает пустота.

Comment: И какой `Content-Type` Вы используйте? И зачем? Angular вроде сам прекрасно все отправляет. И надеюсь у Вас хотя бы `multipart/form-data`.

Если уж проблемы будут с Express, то как вариант сделайте два post, первый с json, как результат id пользователя и по нему post аватар одним файлом
        return this.http.post(this.domain + 'authentication/register', file, options).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! =)